Grid in HTML bugging because of <details>
I want this scores list on my page, started to do the html css about it but already encountered a problem that I cannot find anyone else having. It all works fine until I open the details, then the 2 <p> elements above extend down by a lot.


#ScoresList {
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
}
#ScoresList li {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.ScoreItem {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
.ScoreItem__Score {grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;}
.ScoreItem__Date {grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;}
.ScoreItem__Details {grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 3;}
<ol id="ScoresList">
    <li>
        <div class="ScoreItem">
            <p class="ScoreItem__Score">Score: <span>2500</span></p>
            <p class="ScoreItem__Date">On: <span>25/03/2024</span></p>
            <details class="ScoreItem__Details">
                <summary>More details</summary>
                <p>score</p>
                <p>tijd</p>
                <p>aantal fouten</p>
                <p>foutpercentage</p>
                <p>datum</p>
            </details>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>



Closed

Opened


That's what CSS-Grid does. You might try an alternative layout method.

Can I ask you why you use grid and not a table?

You have specified grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;, which basically means each row should take one (proportionate) "fraction" of the overall height. Opening the dialog changes the height of your second row. But if that new, increased height is what 1fr is now supposed to be equivalent to - then that of course changes the height of your first row as well.

grid-template-rows: auto auto;?

Solution # 1
Your biggest issue lies in setting the columns via grid-area. The 4 values correspond to: row-start, column-start, row-end, column-end.
Accordingly, all 3 of your columns have a row-start and a row-end values of 1, since they are 1-row grids (btw, flex would be sufficient). Based on the photo, I set up my example.

Score: column-start and column-end will 1
Details: column-start and column-end will 2
Date: column-start and column-end will 3

Additionally, to prevent the row from expanding when the details element is expanded, align the items in the row to the baseline.
This just beautifies the code: Use the repeat() function instead of repeating 1fr.


#ScoresList {
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
}
#ScoresList li {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.ScoreItem {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.ScoreItem__Score {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
}
.ScoreItem__Date {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 1 / 3;
}
.ScoreItem__Details {
  /*
    row-start: 1
    column-start: 2
    row-end: 1
    column-end: 2
  */
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
}
<ol id="ScoresList">
  <li>
    <div class="ScoreItem">
      <p class="ScoreItem__Score">Score: <span>2500</span></p>
      <p class="ScoreItem__Date">On: <span>25/03/2024</span></p>
      <details class="ScoreItem__Details">
        <summary>More details</summary>
        <p>score</p>
        <p>tijd</p>
        <p>aantal fouten</p>
        <p>foutpercentage</p>
        <p>datum</p>
      </details>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="ScoreItem">
      <p class="ScoreItem__Score">Score: <span>2500</span></p>
      <p class="ScoreItem__Date">On: <span>25/03/2024</span></p>
      <details class="ScoreItem__Details">
        <summary>More details</summary>
        <p>score</p>
        <p>tijd</p>
        <p>aantal fouten</p>
        <p>foutpercentage</p>
        <p>datum</p>
      </details>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>



If I misunderstood the photo and this would be a 2-row grid layout, where 'More Details' is indeed a second row, then consider this example of mine:


#ScoresList {
  margin: 0 0 0 25px;
}
#ScoresList li {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.ScoreItem {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 5px;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.ScoreItem__Score {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
}
.ScoreItem__Date {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 1 / 2;
}
.ScoreItem__Details {
  /*
    row-start: 2
    column-start: 1
    row-end: 2
    column-end: 2
  */
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  margin: 0 auto; /* or can use text-align: center; */
}
<ol id="ScoresList">
  <li>
    <div class="ScoreItem">
      <p class="ScoreItem__Score">Score: <span>2500</span></p>
      <p class="ScoreItem__Date">On: <span>25/03/2024</span></p>
      <details class="ScoreItem__Details">
        <summary>More details</summary>
        <p>score</p>
        <p>tijd</p>
        <p>aantal fouten</p>
        <p>foutpercentage</p>
        <p>datum</p>
      </details>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="ScoreItem">
      <p class="ScoreItem__Score">Score: <span>2500</span></p>
      <p class="ScoreItem__Date">On: <span>25/03/2024</span></p>
      <details class="ScoreItem__Details">
        <summary>More details</summary>
        <p>score</p>
        <p>tijd</p>
        <p>aantal fouten</p>
        <p>foutpercentage</p>
        <p>datum</p>
      </details>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>




Solution # 2
I think you're just complicating things because of numbering. Assuming you're not statically embedding the data in the code but rather using the results of a query, I would also inject the number via JavaScript into a table. Using a table is by no means outdated for displaying structured data.


table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 20px; /* distance between 2 rows */
}

tr > td {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
<table id="ScoresList">
  <tr class="ScoreItem">
    <td>1.</td>
    <td>
      <p class="ScoreItem__Score">Score: <span>2500</span></p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <details class="ScoreItem__Details">
        <summary>More details</summary>
        <p>score</p>
        <p>tijd</p>
        <p>aantal fouten</p>
        <p>foutpercentage</p>
        <p>datum</p>
      </details>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="ScoreItem__Date">On: <span>25/03/2024</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="ScoreItem">
    <td>2.</td>
    <td>
      <p class="ScoreItem__Score">Score: <span>2500</span></p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <details class="ScoreItem__Details">
        <summary>More details</summary>
        <p>score</p>
        <p>tijd</p>
        <p>aantal fouten</p>
        <p>foutpercentage</p>
        <p>datum</p>
      </details>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p class="ScoreItem__Date">On: <span>25/03/2024</span></p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>




You have your rows set to 1fr, so they all want to be the same height. When the details element is open, the row is taller, so all rows become taller. Therefore, change 1fr 1fr to auto auto.


#ScoresList {
    margin: 0 0 0 25px;
}
#ScoresList li {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.ScoreItem {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 5px;
}
.ScoreItem__Score {grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;}
.ScoreItem__Date {grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;}
.ScoreItem__Details {grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 3;}
<ol id="ScoresList">
    <li>
        <div class="ScoreItem">
            <p class="ScoreItem__Score">Score: <span>2500</span></p>
            <p class="ScoreItem__Date">On: <span>25/03/2024</span></p>
            <details class="ScoreItem__Details">
                <summary>More details</summary>
                <p>score</p>
                <p>tijd</p>
                <p>aantal fouten</p>
                <p>foutpercentage</p>
                <p>datum</p>
            </details>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>



